# MariaDB Import CSV

Tags: mariadb

Afternoon Folks

I am trying to import a CSV into a table on MariaDB

The columns on the table are

```
MariaDB [snipeit]> show columns from locations;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| city       | varchar(191)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| state      | varchar(191)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| country    | varchar(191)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id    | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| address    | varchar(191)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| address2   | varchar(191)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| zip        | varchar(10)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| parent_id  | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| currency   | varchar(10)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ldap_ou    | varchar(191)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| manager_id | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| image      | varchar(191)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The CSV looks like

```
id  name    city    state   country created_at  updated_at  user_id address address2    zip deleted_at  parent_id   currency    ldap_ou manager_id  image
testname NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

id is blank

But the warning shows

```
MariaDB [snipeit]> show warnings;
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                          |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1             |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'created_at' at row 1                  |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'updated_at' at row 1                  |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: 'NULL' for column 'user_id' at row 1    |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'deleted_at' at row 1                  |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: 'NULL' for column 'parent_id' at row 1  |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: 'NULL' for column 'manager_id' at row 1
```

Any idea why this would be?  I thought if a field has NULL I can use NULL  on it?

The command I used to import is

```
 load data local infile '/media/Share1/CSV_Files/test.csv' into TABLE locations fields terminated by ',' ignore 1 lines;
```

Cheers

Comment: How do you plan to map the columns `manager_id` etc. in the CSV file which seem to have no counterpart in the already existing table?

Comment: Apologies updated OP, Shows wrong table

Comment: You have two answers below which seem to be on the right track.

Comment: It is not a CSV file but a TSV file (C for commas, T for tabulations), so you must set separators accordingly if you want to handle that properly with your futures dataloading queries. And of course many others things that are sorted out since last year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of mistakes :

1. Your csv specify 17 columns and your second line (first row of data) has 16 values which means "testname" is used to match the first column ID
   You should remove "id".
2. Your command indicates "fields terminated by ','" but your fields aren't separated by ','. You should separate them with comma.
3. Columns in your csv file don't match columns you have shown to us with "show columns from locations"

Then try to load your file again and tell us if there are other errors.

What you might want to do is :

```
name,city,state,country,created_at,updated_at,user_id,address,address2,zip,deleted_at,parent_id,currency,ldap_ou, manager_id,image;
testname,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,;
```

And use the following command :

```
load data local infile '/media/Share1/CSV_Files/test.csv' into TABLE locations fields terminated by ',' LINE TERMINATED BY ";" ignore 1 lines;
```

EDIT :
Your command should specify columns that appears in your csv file like this (in the right order !!):

```
load data local infile '/media/Share1/CSV_Files/test.csv' into TABLE locations(name,city,state,country,created_at,updated_at,user_id,address,address2,zip,deleted_at,parent_id,currency,ldap_ou,manager_id,image) fields terminated by ',' LINE TERMINATED BY ";" ignore 1 lines;
```

EDIT 2 :

> When reading data with LOAD DATA, empty or missing columns are updated with ''. To load a NULL value into a column, use \N in the data file. The literal word NULL may also be used under some circumstances. See Section 13.2.7, “LOAD DATA Syntax”.

from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-null.html

So your csv should look like :

```
name,city,state,country,created_at,updated_at,user_id,address,address2,zip,deleted_at,parent_id,currency,ldap_ou, manager_id,image;
testname,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N;
```

EDIT 3 : It may be the final solution. Do not specify id field in the csv file as just above in EDIT 2. And use the following command :

```
load data local infile '/media/Share1/CSV_Files/test.csv' 
into table locations
fields terminated by ',' 
line terminated by ";" 
ignore 1 lines
(name,city,state,country,created_at,updated_at,user_id,address,address2,zip,deleted_at,parent_id,currency,ldap_ou,manager_id,image)
set id = null;
```

Comment: It's ok, I have edited my answer with some others suggestions, do not hesitate to accept my answer if everything's is ok after that. Thanks

Comment: Very quickly. Thanks for the \N , inputting \N in the null fields I dont want work fine. BUT If i remove the id field all the fields will be NULL.. Anyway entering the id field but keeping it blank seems to work fine. The command that works for me is ``` load data local infile '/media/Share1/CSV_Files/test.csv' into TABLE locations fields terminated by ',' ignore 1 lines; ``` when I use your (name,city,blah blah) it complains the syntax is incorrect. The only warning I have now is ``` Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1 ```

Comment: To fix "Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1" you should try to use \N instead of keeping it blank

Answer (score 1):

Since `id` is an `auto_increment` field it is generated automatically. You need to remove `id` column from the CSV file.